# How to set up a URL variable to be used in NUnit/SpecFlow framework

Tags: c#, nunit, automated-tests, specflow

I'd like to extend the Test Harness I have written in SpecFlow to be a bit more extensible, so what I would like to do is in the setup create a base URL variable that I can set depending on a flag I use on the Nunit runner.  So if I send in Test as a Tag I want some URL value to be set to "http://test/" or for Development to set URL to "http://dev/".  I know Global variables are not useful in NUnit, most of my previous scripting was in Perl where even then I used it on rare occasions.  I'm not sure I am doing this right, although I get the code to compile without errors the URL never get's set.  What I am doing is a check when the NUnit runner starts:

```
private static testInfoConfiguration myUrl;
public static string baseUrl = string.Empty;
[BeforeFeature("Test")]
public static void BeforeFeature_Test()
{

    myUrl = new testInfoConfiguration();
    baseUrl = myUrl.setBaseUrl("Test");
}
```

Which calls this:

```
public class testInfoConfiguration
{
public string setBaseUrl(string envType)
    {
        string envUrl;
        if (envType == "Test")
        {
            envUrl = "http://testweb/";
            return envUrl;
        }
        if (envType == "Prod")
        {
            envUrl = "http://www/";
            return envUrl;
        }
        envUrl = "http://devweb/";
        return envUrl;
    }
```

I then want to make a call to the URL variable later on:

```
[When(@"I access the Web Site")]
public void WhenIAccessTheWebSite()
{
    string kcUrl = baseUrl + "/knowledge/Pages/default.aspx";
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(kcUrl);
```

When I call the URL variable it's still empty.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm still learning C#, NUnit and SpecFlow so I am probably just not looking at the right aspect of this to where I am going wrong.  Or just really not understanding how to set a variable in this manner.

Edit: Adjusting the existing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this block of code:

```
private static testInfoConfiguration myUrl; 
public string baseUrl = "";     
[BeforeFeature("Test")] 
public static string BeforeFeature_Test() 
{ 

    myUrl = new testInfoConfiguration(); 
    string baseUrl = myUrl.setBaseUrl("Test"); 
    return baseUrl; 
}
```

You're defining `baseUrl` twice: once in the scope of the method, and once in the scope of the class.

When you're in this block of code:

```
string kcUrl = baseUrl + "/knowledge/Pages/default.aspx";      
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(kcUrl);
```

You're referring to (what I assume) is the instance field `baseUrl`, which you never set.

Try the following:

```
private static testInfoConfiguration myUrl; 
public static string baseUrl = string.Empty;     
[BeforeFeature("Test")] 
public static void BeforeFeature_Test() 
{ 
    myUrl = new testInfoConfiguration(); 
    baseUrl = myUrl.setBaseUrl("Test");       
}
```

Comment: This definitely get's me closer, and thanks for the scope lesson I am still grasping with that.  Although I am finding the string kcUrl = baseUrl ends up with an empty baseUrl.  Is this my return in the setBaseUrl function?

Comment: Without seeing all of the involved code, I can't really tell. Update your question with more of your code and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Ok, updated although I don't know what else is necessary. As far as I can tell there shouldn't be any other code being called at this point since I am just setting the url variable right away.  When the Test Runs the browser URL shows up as:  http:///knowledge/Pages/default.aspx so it's getting the latter part of the string concatenation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure that they're both part of the same feature? I see `[BeforeFeature("Test")]`. If your method `WhenIAccessTheWebSite()` isn't part of that same feature, it's probably not executing the setup method. Put a breakpoint and check if `BeforeFeature_Test()` is being executed.

Comment: Now I am having a Doh moment, I forgot to reset the tag.  Works perfect now...thank you very much!